# Finding a good structure for multiple apps in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

This is the situation i am currently having issues with:

I have 1 webserver, this webserver must run 2 different websites, those websites are all written in symfony2 and share the same Bundle that i wrote.
Currently this bundle is placed in the src/ folder and loaded in the AppKernel.
Right now i am using the apps approach where i have 2 seperate app folders created in 1 folder called apps ( http://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2 )
However right now my situation changed, i have this 1 webserver with 2 different websites but i also have a second webserver which must also be able to have multiple apps. 
Both servers should not share the same configuration files which is having me a lot of difficulties with deploying.
I also want to prevent that i have to deploy unused bundles to a server.

I hope i explained everything as clear as possible, it is not easy to make a description.

Answer (score 0):

As I read, the app folder contains all config or not files related to the app ( doctrine, Kernel, cache, logs, etc). Routing, Services or other files related to how works an specific bundle should be within that bundle in my opinion.

I think there is not a standard or good way to do this because symfony right know has the workflow one app - one project. Any structure which separates bundle config  and app con
fig is valid if don't mix both kinds

Comment: For the shared src folders would it be better if i converted those bundles to a vendor and manage them with composer ?

Comment: That depends. Do you think to reuse that funcionality in a wide range of projects ? If so, the cost is worthy.

Comment: Yes i am using it in the projects that run my website (it is designed to work as a cms ) however its only for 1 specific type of websites and not a variaty of types (only for 1 specific game)